# Installing a floor for storage above detached garage?

Tags: floor, garage, attic, joists

We have a gabled-roof single-story detached garage with horizontal 2x4 beams spaced four feet apart and a 20' span.  There are two vertical 2x4 beams connecting the two horizontal center beams to the roof.  There are also 1x6 diagonal braces connecting the roof to every joist.

I'd like to install plywood flooring above most of it for storage.  Nothing that we put up there will be too heavy, but I'm certain I'd need to provide additional support.  I would plan to walk on the floor to store and retrieve things.

What size and spacing of supplemental joists would be reasonable to support a floor?  How should they be safely secured to the existing structure?  And what thickness should the plywood floor be for reasonable support?  Should I consult with a structural engineer?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The following may be duplicates.

- [Is my attic floor over my garage strong enough to use it for storage and maybe as a small work area?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/55306/9750)
- [Can I use the area above my garage for storage?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/37914/9750)
- [Can I lay down plywood in my attic to create a storage space?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2039/9750)

Comment: What's the span? Nobody can use span tables to look up the joist size, without knowing what the span is.

Comment: I'll go take some pictures and make some measurements and update the question.  It's a smallish two car garage and the joists run perpendicular to the cars.

Comment: probably 16-18 foot joists.

Comment: 2 car garage is probably 18-24'. For 2x10 southern pine, 30 psf live 10 psf dead, you're looking at Dense Select Structural (DSS) grade 12" O.C. for 21' span. Any wider than that, you're going to have to look at other options (middle support, engineered joists, etc.).

Comment: In [my situation](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/37914/33), I put just enough plywood up there to create a catwalk. And I only store holiday decorations, and other light objects up there.

Comment: Are you sure those are joists and not rafter ties? Often, they are one in the same, but if the intent was for them to primarily be rafter ties, they're likely not 'engineered' to also act as floor joists.

Comment: @Tester101 see my revised measurements and photos.

Comment: @DA01 I don't know, it's very possible I'm using incorrect terminology.

Comment: @glenviewjeff Those are not joists/rafters. They're there to prevent the roof from flattening out, and are not designed to support anything on top of them.

Comment: Good to know! :)  So how can I safely support a floor up there?  Also, what should I call these supports in my question?

Comment: If you want to use the area as storage, you're going to have to build a floor  independent of these members.

Comment: Any guidance about how to do so?  I.e., how and where to attach joists to the walls, and will the joists need additional support?

Comment: ah, yes, the photo helps a lot. Those are indeed just rafter ties. You can certainly stick a piece of plywood up there and use it to store things like that ladder, but if you want an actual floor to walk on and store heavy objects, then you need to install actual floor joists. Doable, but might just be easier to build a shed somewhere else in the yard.

Comment: @DA01 yes, apparently a far bigger project than I had originally envisioned!  I originally thought it might be as simple as screwing in some extra 2x4s and laying down plywood, but I'm glad I sought advice.  I'll just use it as-is unless/until I really need more substantial storage.

Comment: I'm glad you've gotten good advice above. One of my upcoming jobs is to fix some rafter ties cracked by people trying to build "free" storage just like this. Turns out it wasn't free.